# Render different component depending on route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What I'm trying to achieve is to render different content surrounding view depending upon the routing url. I'm using `react-router`.

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div> //this is when Login component
          {this.props.children}

           //something like this when it is any page except login
          <Sidebar />
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
          <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Login} />
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="publisher-list" component={PublisherList}/>
              <Route path="/edit-publisher/:id" component={EditPublisher}/>
            <Route path="add-publisher" component={AddPublisher}/>
            <Route path="add-professional" component={AddProfessional}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

My problem is how to hide sidebar when it is a login page and show sidebar on rest pages. How can I do this...?

*I haven't included the imports, assume all imports are included.

Consider this as an example of an admin portal side. First thing thing that you want to see is a login page. So no sidebar or navbar is needed. But once he logs in all view must contain sidebar and navbar by default..So `www.admin.com/` or `www.admin.com/login` should be login page and the rest URLs..like `www.admin.com/publisher-list` or `www.admin.com/professional` etc should have the navbar and sidebar.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want `app` to be different depending on what sub-route you're on?

Comment: Yes...is it possible..? Or is there some other way to do so..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (!localStorage.jwt) {
            replaceState({nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}, '/login');
        }
    }
}

function disallowLogin(nextState, replaceState) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.jwt) {
            replaceState({nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}, '/');
        }
    }
}

export default (
    <Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={disallowLogin}/>
        <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
          Your routes here            
        </Route>
    </Route>
);
```

So basically:

Whenever someone visits your page, he gets redirected to Login unless he has JWT in his localStorage. If he will be authenticated then he will proceed to admin app.

The other way around is probably with

```
var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {isAuthenticated: true/false});
})
```

And then you could have in every children to render or not it depending on the result of isAuthenticated props.
Though Sidebar would need to be a childrne then.

The last case would be different rendering in Sidebar only, depending on the case if someone is logged in or not

```
render() {
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
       return <Sidebar />
    } else {
       return <div/>
}
```

Also if you are storing logged person token somewhere in his browser (i.e. localStorage) then you could simply check if he has a token over there (which would basically mean that he is logged in) and then display it like above though instead of isAuthenticated you would have a different case

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would to simply create another component and the sub-routes with the different styling in there:

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <Route path="/" component={App1}>
    <IndexRoute component={Login} />
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="add-professional" component={AddProfessional}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/publisher" component={App2}>
    <IndexRoute component={PublisherList} />
    <Route path="edit/:id" component={EditPublisher}/>
    <Route path="add" component={AddPublisher}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

this way you can set different layout for `app1` and `app2`.

*Alternative:*

You can add some conditionals inside your `app` to check for the current url with `this.props.location.pathname` and play around with conditionals on that. Though, depending on your application, it may not be advisable to do so.

Comment: I have updated question for a further explaination. If I go by your anwer then I would have to create more parent component like `App2`. `App2` is fine but the path should be simply `/` instead of  `/publisher`..